# AudioGraph DesiredSamplesPerQuantum property is ignored

Tags: c#, audio, uwp

I'm developping a UWP audio application. Latest Windows 10 SDK version 1803.

I would like to increase the SamplesPerQuantum used on the AudioGraph of my application.
According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs), I should specify the properties DesiredSamplesPerQuantum and QuantumSizeSelectionMode before creating the AudioGraph.

I'm creating the AudioGraph like this :

```
AudioGraphSettings settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media);
settings.DesiredSamplesPerQuantum = 960; // 20ms
settings.QuantumSizeSelectionMode = QuantumSizeSelectionMode.ClosestToDesired;
CreateAudioGraphResult result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);
Debug.WriteLine("SamplesPerQuantum=" + result.Graph.SamplesPerQuantum);
```

I tried everything, the SamplesPerQuantum property is always 480...

It's a problem because I get clicks in the audio output at each garbage collection. I think the default quantum of 10ms is too short...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried everything, the SamplesPerQuantum property is always 480...

By default, the quantum size is 10 ms based at the default sample rate.  The system will choose a quantum size as close as possible to the one you specify. if your the sample rate of speak device is limited to 48000hz, the `SamplesPerQuantum` will be limited to 480. For your requirement, you could set sample rate to  96000hz. Then your setting could be available.

[image]

I have discussed with media team, and they give the following reply. The general idea is `DesiredSamplesPerQuantum` related with your hardware.

**Update**

*The behavior the customer is seeing is dependent on the underlying audio hardware. The `DesiredSamplesPerQuantum` property is only a suggestion to the underlying hardware. If the hardware / driver does not support the requested quantum then it will not be set. 
When the GC runs there may be clicks or pops in the audio. This is because managed languages are nondeterministic.*

And this is James Dailey's [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mediasdkstuff/2009/04/01/calling-the-format-sdk-directshow-media-foundation-or-the-wasapi-from-managed-code-c-vb-net/) that you could refer.

Comment: Yes, but a 960 SamplesPerQuantum at 96000 hz  would still be 10ms. I would like to have 20 ms or more...

Comment: Can you tell me how 10ms is derived?

Comment: If it is related with sample rate, you could modify `EncodingProperties` property.

Comment: The doc says : "By default, the quantum size is 10 ms based at the default sample rate". I guess 480 is for 10 ms...

Comment: Yes, I was able to change the sample rate for example to 22050 Hz. But then the SamplesPerQuantum was 220. Still 10ms ! I would like to be able to have more latency and a bigger buffer to see if the clicks produced by the garbage collecter disappear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183766/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-nicolas-seveno).

Comment: hi @NicolasSéveno I have updated the answer, please check.

Comment: OK, thank you @NicoZhuMSFT for taking time to answer ! About the 10ms limit, I will try with an external soundcard to see if it changes something. About the GC clicks, I will optimize my code as much as possible to reduce the blocking GC collections. After some optimizations, it is already better...